# Estimating false accept rates from imposter scores below a threshold

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, false-positive-rate, truncated-distributions

I have a system that compares two items and produces a match score.  Scores below a threshold are manually inspected to determine if they match or don't(imposter).  Scores above the threshold are assumed to match with no further testing.  Can I use the distribution of imposter scores below threshold to estimate the imposters above threshold that were assumed to match (false accept rate)?  If no, how can I estimate the false accept rate without testing those above threshold?  During system test where all items were verified the distribution of imposter scores was lognormal.

Comment: So for all the scores that were below a threshold you manually inspect them, save all these results, get a distribution, and now you want to `estimate the imposters above threshold that were assumed to match (false accept rate)`; can you explain better what you mean by this?

Comment: That is correct.  I know the distribution of scores for the imposters that are below the threshold that the system identifies and are prevent from going forward.  I want to estimate how many are above threshold.  Basically, I want to know what gets past the system that should not.

Comment: I don't understand. You say that the imposters are defined as being below the threshold, but then you say you `want to estimate how many are above threshold`? None of them? Since they are all below the threshold?